# parse pages of online book and save content of pages and its footers without any changes

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

```
<article class="js_IntraTCBP IntraTCBP dr tr lh2 js_lblContent" id="js_lblContent"><p></p>text
<p></p><p></p><a name="p1"></a><a name="p1"></a><a name="p1"></a><a name="p1"></a><a name="p1"></a><h1>text</h1><p></p><p></p>text
<p></p>text<sup>1</sup>
<p></p>text<sup>2</sup>
<p></p>text<sup>3</sup>
<p></p>text<sup>4</sup>text<p></p><hr class="Footer"><p></p><font class="Footer"><p></p>1-ddd
<p></p>2-ccc

<p></p>3-bbb

<p></p>4-aaa

</font></article>
```

text

## text

text

text<sup>1</sup>

text<sup>2</sup>

text<sup>3</sup>

text<sup>4</sup>text

1-ddd

2-ccc

3-bbb

4-aaa

I want to parse pages of online book and save content of pages without any changes.

when I use this:

var pageContent = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@class='js_IntraTCBP IntraTCBP dr tr lh2 js_lblContent']/text()");

it get me all 'text's.

how can I get all footers. for example text1 ----> 1=dddd. like what I see in book's page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try regular expressions or Regex, which are sequences of characters and symbols which express a string or pattern to search for. [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use `Regex.Matches` to match some html elements, but you have to loop through each line. This will get you started:

```
// loop...

var matches = Regex.Match(line, @"(\<[\w]*\>|[^\s]*([^<]*)\<\/[\w]*\>)");
```

To get the tag including content use:

```
string tag = matches.Groups[1].Value;
```

To get the content no incuding the tag use:

```
string content = matches.Groups[2].Value;
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sB2xJ7/1). It can detect some elements but not all.

Here are some links that may help with learning it:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex

Comment: I don't understand regex well. can anyone help me more?
please say another way or more explain that.